# QSTK: install problems

Tags: macos, qstk

I am trying to install QSTK on my Mac 10.7.5, but the error is shown below, can anyone help me with that??

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.1: 1024 files, 119M
Installing numpy, scipy, matplotlib
numpy: Unsatisfied dependency: nose
External Python cannot `import nose`. Install with:
  sudo easy_install pip
  pip-2.5 install nose
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
numpy: Unsatisfied dependency: nose
External Python cannot `import nose`. Install with:
  sudo easy_install pip
  pip-2.5 install nose
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
matplotlib: Unsatisfied dependency: dateutil
External Python cannot `import dateutil`. Install with:
  sudo easy_install pip
  pip-2.5 install python-dateutil
matplotlib: Unsatisfied dependency: pyparsing
External Python cannot `import pyparsing`. Install with:
  sudo easy_install pip
  pip-2.5 install pyparsing
numpy: Unsatisfied dependency: nose
External Python cannot `import nose`. Install with:
  sudo easy_install pip
  pip-2.5 install nose
Error: Unsatisifed requirements failed this build.
Create QSTK directory
mkdir: /Users/wcf/QSTK: File exists
Install pandas, scikits
bash: line 42: pip: command not found
bash: line 43: pip: command not found
bash: line 44: pip: command not found
bash: line 45: pip: command not found
vagvlan536:~ wcf$
```

Answer (score 0):

... isn't it telling you the answer right there?  Did you try what it said?:

sudo easy_install pip

pip-2.5 install nose

pip-2.5 install python-dateutil

pip-2.5 install pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a python conflict between the system (/usr/bin) and the brew (/usr/local/Cellar).

Suggest you try out the following:

1. >which python - if the result come back with /usr/bin , you are not at the correct path.
2. >brew doctor - follow the instruction to overwrite link for python and gdbm. 
   e.g. `brew link --overwrite python`.
3. Reinstall nose and numpy again should work.